# Javascript -> Why are my cookies not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have a react app where I want the user to log in and once the user logs in successfully the `loginStatus` would be saved in a state called `loginState` which then would be saved on a `cookie` with the path value of the `app.js` file. I have a second cookie created on the same login page that would keep the user's username so that once they go to the profilepage it would greet them by their username. The problem is that the two cookies are set on different paths but they seem to overwrite one another. Why is that and how do I fix it? Here's the relevant code:

That is the function creating my cookies for the profile page

```
    const createCookie=(username)=>{
      let date = new Date()
      let hours = 1
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(hours*60*60*1000))
      document.cookie=`${username}; expires=${date.toUTCString()}; path=./ProfilePage`
}
```

And that is where I am creating the cookies for my app.js:

```
            if(user.isLoggedIn){
                setLoginStatus('logged in')
                document.cookie=`${loginStatus}; path=../App`
                let x = document.cookie;
                console.log(x)
            }
```

Now there's my app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    let cookie = document.cookie;
    console.log(cookie)
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router> 
            
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/Home' component={Home}/>

                <Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>
                <Route path='/Register' component={Register}/>
                <Route path='/ProfilePage' component={ProfilePage}/>
                <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />

            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
```

and I do the same with the cookies in the profilepage js file.

Comment: Cookies and react? Why not state or localStorage?

Comment: I am using state?

Comment: Add a cookie name , and the loginStatus can be set on the domain, so path can be removed. And for profilePage modify path as `path=/ProfilePage`

Comment: @AkashPal your solution has worked, Thank you a bunch !! If you would like put the comment as an answer and I'd gladly accept it

Comment: @Python_Mython79 great, happy to help. I have added the comment as answer

Comment: Accepted it :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cookie name , and the loginStatus can be set on the domain, so path can be removed. And for profilePage modify path as `path=/ProfilePage`